# Left Outer Join in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, the first having more rows than the second.

I am trying to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to put these two tables together in SQLite but I keep getting an error message.

The query I am running is:

```
SELECT a.object, a.id, b.objectName 
FROM tableOne a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableTwo b ON a.id=b.id
```

The error message I get is:

```
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Comment: This error generally means there is a syntax error.  The query in the posting looks fine.  I suspect that your actual query is different.  SQLite supports left outer join.

Comment: `SELECT a.object, a.id, b.objectName 
FROM "tableOne" a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tableTwo" b ON a.id=b.id ` works?

Comment: are you sure that fields exist? Are you sure a.id = b.id?

Comment: Wow, it worked after I added the quotes to the table names. Thanks, @Alexander! And yea, the query looked correct to me, that's why I was so confused. Thanks again!

Comment: What were the actual table names? Any special characters?

Comment: @hlee yw. I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolate table names:

```
SELECT a.object, 
       a.id, 
       b.objectName 
  FROM "tableOne" a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "tableTwo" b 
            ON a.id=b.id
```